# Will "persistent" data from USB "try Ubuntu" be saved when I install it to my laptop?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I'm using Quantal from a USB stick (created with Linux Live USB Creator) with persistence. If at a later I choose to install Ubuntu to a laptop (using the "Install" icon) will my changes be included in the installation?